# Simple Ruby Chris Pine Leap Year

Tags: ruby

Hi I need help with a question from Chris Pines book that asks to list the leap years between a starting and ending year. I have seen it done other ways but I was wondering if there was anyway to make this code work? Whats wrong with it? I'm new to programming. Thanks!
It gives this error.

```
(eval):22: (eval):22: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):22: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

My program:

```
def years(starting, ending)
  while starting <= ending
    while (starting % 4 == 0) && (starting % 400 == 0)
      puts starting
    unless starting % 100 == 0
  end
  starting += 1
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You haven't told us how it's not working. "Whats wrong with it?" without explaining what "wrong" is to us is meaningless. (You should also learn how to properly format code here; there's a help button at the top right of the text area, or you can simply select your code and either use `Ctrl+K` or the toolbar button with the `{}` image. You can also just indent each line by four or more spaces. You can preview before you post right below the text area where you're entering it. Property formatting helps get you answers more quickly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the `while` loop in your code is missing an `end` statements.

Without checking for the correctness of the logic, the code itself would be structured as follows:

```
def years(starting, ending)
  while starting <= ending
    while (starting % 4 == 0) && (starting % 400 == 0)
      puts starting unless starting % 100 == 0
    end
    starting += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the date method leap? it will return true or false

```
require 'date'
def leap_year?(year)
  Date.new(year).leap?
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F